# Nesting a Button or TouchableHighlight inside a TouchableHighlight

Tags: react-native, button

I have a component that I made "touchable" using a `TouchableHighlight` (highlighted in red ink in the screenshot below). However, inside this component, I want another component with its own `onPress` handler (highlighted in blue ink below).

How do I achieve this?

[image: grid with TouchableHighlight]

Comment: Probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832755/nested-touchable-with-absolute-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log("something 01")}>
    <View>
        //some code
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log("something 02")}></TouchableHighlight>
        //some code
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```